# Newbie: XLST 1.0 node-set variable lookup by position?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Trying to write an XSLT 1.0 template that will create elements from the Filemaker FMPXMLRESULT METADATA/@NAME attribute. Here's sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Type" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Level" TYPE="TEXT"/>
</METADATA>
<RESULTSET FOUND="2">
    <ROW MODID="18" RECORDID="28133">
        <COL><DATA>O1</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>L1</DATA></COL>
    </ROW>
    <ROW MODID="5" RECORDID="28153">
        <COL><DATA>D12</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>L1</DATA></COL>
    </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

And here's my XLST progress so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:variable name="labels" select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD/@NAME"/>

<xsl:template match="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <PLAN>
            <xsl:for-each select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
                <Sign>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL">
                        <xsl:element name="{$labels[position()]}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Sign>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PLAN>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My trouble is in line 13:

```
<xsl:element name="{$labels[position()]}">
```

Where position() doesn't relate to the position of fmp:COL, and likely is meaningless the way I've used it.

What I'd like to reference is the current fmp:COL element in the xsl:for-each loop, but I suspect that this can't be obtained in XLST 1.0 given the way I'm approaching it.

Does anyone have suggestions or pointers on how to proceed?

Many thanks!

Charles

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question/answer. It might be what you are looking for.
[Filemaker XSL Select Column By Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994751/filemaker-xsl-select-column-by-name)

Update:
This post also has great solutions to a similar question:
[XSLT question. How to pair field tags with data when original XML has them in separate sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121171/xslt-question-how-to-pair-field-tags-with-data-when-original-xml-has-them-in-sep)